# User-input prime number generator

Tags: python, primes, python-3.x

1. What do you consider the readability of this program?
2. Do you think it's easy to understand what the variables and functions do just by reading their names?
3. Would you prefer more, less, or this amount of comments?
4. Do the comments make it easier or harder for you to understand the program?
5. Do you like a program to have comments (in general)?

```
# This program generates prime numbers

# Introduces user
def welcome():
    print("""
         Welcome to the prime number generator!

         This program genarates all prime numbers starting from zero
         to an upper limit. You´ll decide the upper limit.

         Have fun :)
         """)

# User inputs a natural number that will be the upper limit for checking primenumbers
def limit(question):
    while True:
        try:
            limit = int(input(question))
        except:
            limit = ""
        if limit:
            return limit
            break

# Checks if the number is a prime number. If it is, the number will be returned. If it is not, then None will be returned
def is_it_prime(current_number, prime_number):
    y = 0
    while True:
        ratio = current_number / prime_number[y]
        y += 1
        if ratio == int(ratio):
            break
        if y == len(prime_number):
            return current_number

# Adds prime number to list
def ad_prime(prime_number, it_is_prime):
    a = len(prime_number)
    prime_temp = (a+1)*[None]
    for i in range(a):
        prime_temp[i] = prime_number[i]
        if i+1 == a:
            prime_temp[i+1] = it_is_prime
    return prime_temp

# Main program
upper_limit_question = "Type the upper limit and press enter. It has to be a natural number expressed in digits: "
lower_limit = 2
prime_number = [2]
welcome()
upper_limit = limit(upper_limit_question)
while lower_limit < upper_limit:
    lower_limit +=1
    it_is_prime = is_it_prime(lower_limit, prime_number)
    if it_is_prime != None:
        prime_number = ad_prime(prime_number, it_is_prime)
print("\n" +str(prime_number), "\n\nThanks for generating prime numbers :)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to get a general understanding of what your code does.  You did a good job separating the code into functions.  It could be made more readable in a few ways though, mostly by doing things in a simpler way.  For example, your `add_prime` function (which appends a number to the end of a list) could be written in one line (I'll get to how later).

I recommend reading the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).  By the time you get to chapter 4, you'll notice a lot of thing you would have done differently. :)

The variable names are good and make it easy to follow what you're doing, but the are a couple of names that are a bit confusing.  In particular, `prime_number` should be `prime_numbers` or simply `primes` because it is a list of numbers.  Also, `limit` isn't very descriptive at all.  The difference between the `limit` function and the `upper_limit` variable is that one gets the value from the user, and the other stores it.  `limit` should be `get_limit` or `get_limit_from_user`.

I like the way you comment.  The amount of comments is good and they improve readability.  Keep commenting like that.  I have one note, though:  When you're writing a comment that describes what a whole function or a whole program does, use a **docstring**.  This makes it clearer to other programmers what you commenting about, and makes it possible to access the comment in the code.

Here is what an improved version of the code could look like (comments starting with `##` are part of this review and don't belong to the program):

```
"""Generate prime numbers."""    ## This is a docstring.


WELCOME_TEXT = """Welcome to the prime number generator!

This program generates all prime numbers starting from zero to an upper limit.
You'll decide the upper limit.

Have fun :)
"""

LIMIT_PROMPT = ("Type the upper limit and press enter. It has to be a natural "
                "number expressed in digits: ")
```

`ALL_CAPS_NAMES` are a convention meaning a value should be treated as constant.  In general, you should set constant values at the start of your program.  In this case, this also has the advantage that the `WELCOME_TEXT` won't be indented.

The two strings in `LIMIT_PROMPT` will automatically be concatenated.  This way, you can write a one-line string in two lines of code.

```
def welcome():
    """Introduce user."""    ## Also a docstring.  If your function definition starts 
    print(WELCOME_TEXT)      ## with a string, the string will be made a docstring.


def get_limit():
    """Let user input a an upper limit for checking prime numbers.

    The input must be a natural number."""

    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(LIMIT_PROMPT))
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

I made a few changes to the `get_limit` function.  You should always catch only specific exceptions (`ValueError` in this case.) Also, I think it's better not to mix strings and numbers in one variable.

```
def is_prime(current_number, prime_numbers):
    """Check whether the number is a prime number.

    prime_numbers must contain all prime numbers lower than current_number."""

    for prime in prime_numbers:
        if current_number % prime == 0:    ## (current_number % prime) is the remainder
            return False                   ## when current_number is divided by prime.
    return True
```

You can loop over a list can be done easier this way.  Making `is_prime` return a boolean will make things easier for you in the main part of the program.

```
def main():
    welcome()
    upper_limit = get_limit()
    prime_numbers = []
    for number in range(2, upper_limit+1):
        if is_prime(number, prime_numbers):
            prime_numbers.append(number)    ## This adds number to the end of prime_numbers,
                                            ## so you don't need add_prime anymore.
    print("\n", prime_numbers, "\n\nThanks for generating prime numbers :)")

main()
```

I put the main part of the program into a `main` function (this is a useful convention).  Again, you can simplify the loop, this time using the `range` function.  For simple loops, there is usually a way of using a very readable `for` loop instead of a `while` loop.  I also changed the name `lower_limit` to `number`, which fits better in my opinion.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask them.  Welcome to codereview. :)

Comment: If you catch only ValueErrors, you will immediatly when notice a different exception is thrown. Let's say you type `return int(input(LIMITPROMPT))` (note the missing underscore in `LIMIT_PROMPT`). This will throw a `NameError`. With a bare `except:`, this error will be silently ignored and the program will be caught in an infinite loop. With `except ValueError:`, however, you will notice the typo because you will get an error message.

Comment: I deleted the comment that flornquake answered. Posting it again: When the `ValueError` statement is removed the program seems to be working fine. Why is the `ValueError` statement good?

Comment: Is it not an infinite loop anaway (in this case)?

Comment: Well, yes, but what I meant is that if you have a bare `except:` and a typo as in `return int(input(LIMITPROMPT))`, your program won't ask you for input anymore.  Instead, it will get stuck in an infinite loop you can't break out of, unless you interrupt the program.

Comment: If the code stays the same except that `ValueError` is removed. It still asks for input. And when running it shows the same reults.

Comment: True, as long as no other exceptions are thrown.  But if you make a mistake and the code throws an unexpected exception (e.g. when you make a typo), the `except` will catch the exception. This is not what you want because it will hide the underlying problem instead of printing a useful error message.